# What does (a[i] = b[i]) != 0 mean in a c strcpy implementation?

Tags: c

In a simplified strcpy(a, b) function I saw such implementation:

```
for (i = 0; (a[i] = b[i]) != 0; i++) ;
```

I saw the above statement in a c string copy implementation. I assume it is assigning a[i] to b[i], and then check if a[i] is the termination character?

1. In which order does the above execute? Does it start with the not equal checking first or the assignment? And is it checking on array a or b?
2. Is it OK to write code in this compact way as this might cause confusion?

Comment: Parenthesis are a pretty good indicator for what's evaluated first. The `X != 0` needs to evaluate `X` before it can evaluate the comparison. Without the parenthesis, you'd have to deferr to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), where the assignment would occur afterwards. But your understanding of what the statement does is correct. When you call `a[i] = b[i]`, it will assign to `a[i]` and return its new value in `a[i]`. Typically you'd avoid such compact code for readability, but it's more of a style/opinion question at that point.

Comment: Whether it's okay or not depends on your policies and such.  As an experienced C programmer, it was perfectly clear to me, though the normal idiom is a while loop using pointers, something like `while ( (*a++ = *b++) ) ;` (where the comparison to zero is implicit)

Comment: "*Is it OK to write code in this compact way?*"  That's a matter of style and opinion, but I think code clarity is an important criterion.  I would not write that particular code, precisely because it's difficult to follow.  I suspect that some people, especially less experienced ones, assume that compactness correlates with speed, but it's not nearly that simple.

Comment: An assignment like `a = b` does not only assign `b` to `a` but is is also a full fledged expression whose value is the result of the assignment, so `printf("%d", a = b)` will assign `b` to `a` and print the value of `b` (or `a`, doesn't really matter because after the assignmenet `a` is the same as `b`).

Comment: @Jabberwocky unless the types are different and a type conversion occurs, then it's significant whether the value is the source or target.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

1. A for loop always checks the condition first
2. "OK" depends on context of course.  If you code like this on a team project, someone is likely to get upset with you.  If you do it in your own code and you understand it, then it is OK.